# Is it possible to use BQ25629 as both a lipo battery charger and a stable output regulator?

Tags: battery-charging, buck, lipo, pmic, voltage-regulator

I am a bit confused looking at the datasheet for the TI [BQ25629](https://www.ti.com/product/BQ25629) with regards to the SYS output voltage. Essentially, I have a 3.7 nominal voltage 290 mAh lipo battery that needs to provide around 100 mA continuous current at peak demand. The system load consists of a MCU and a device that is sensitive to voltage variation; ripple voltage should be less than 50 mV. That is, I want to to ensure that output of the regulator is consistently 3.0 V across the range of the battery life.

When looking at the BQ25629, I do not understand how to set the system output of the regulator, or whether my understanding of this is entirely wrong (very likely). Do I need to add an additional regulator downstream to BQ25629 to ensure stable 3.0 V? Given the datasheet is vague about the output regulation voltage level, I am probably understanding the purpose of SW output regulation incorrectly.

System Diagram below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTmdX4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Do I need to add an additional regulator downstream to BQ25629 to
> ensure stable 3.0 V?*

Any regulation facilities it has (or uses) are for the efficient charging of batteries and not for regulating the external circuits that you might wish to connect to the SYS output. It's a battery charger and not some power supply regulator. The marketing people at Texas Instruments would certainly have made sure you knew about any added regulation facilities for an external load should there have been any.

In other words, if your circuit won't correctly-work solely from a battery across its full charge range, then neither will it do so when using the BQ25629 charger and the battery.

Comment: Just to add a little to the answer: The part does have a configurable minimum system voltage that can be above the battery voltage.  If the battery is below the minimum sys voltage the part charges the battery through an internal FET operating in linear mode.  So you could set the minimum system voltage to 3 V, but as the battery charges up above 3 V, the system voltage will rise along with it.

Comment: So something like the BQ25629 is used when the system is operating solely off of the battery? Or I can have a PMIC regulate the battery down to 3.0V when in battery mode but when a USB is connected switch the PMIC input since the battery will be charging from the BQ25629?

Comment: @tronhawk the data sheet implies you connect your load the SYS output. I would go searching for application notes on the BQ25629 and find a circuit that suits your application or, ask a new question here (but provide a circuit proposal in that question).

Comment: @Andyaka thanks. New to BMS and PMICs so learning how to read these datasheets.